# error converting numeric to data type numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
ALTER    function [APP].[FN_DCT_Mod97_2]

 (@code as numeric)


 RETURNS numeric

AS 

BEGIN

declare @cd as numeric= (98-(@code % 97))

return @cd

end
```

```
select  [APP].[FN_DCT_Mod97_2]  (1234567890123456789)
```

I execute this with less numbers and works, how i can make it work with more numbers?

Comment: Declare your precision and scale for your `numeric`... *(I still don't understand why so many people don't declare scale or precisions for `decimal` and `varchar` datatypes...)*  By default declaring a value as `numeric` will create a `numeric(18,0)`. `1234567890123456789` has 19 numbers; and thus is too large.

Comment: thanks you a lot, works now.

Answer (score 1):

You have to mention the range of the `NUMERIC` value, otherwise it fix the minimum value to it.

Try this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [APP].[FN_DCT_Mod97_2](@code AS NUMERIC(38,2))
RETURNS NUMERIC
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @cd AS NUMERIC(38,2)
    SELECT @cd = (98-(@code % 97))
RETURN @cd
END
```

Then use the Function:

```
SELECT  [APP].[FN_DCT_Mod97_2]  (1234567890123456789)
```

**OutPut:**

```
88
```